# Rename csrfmiddlewaretoken

Tags: python, django

I use Django and in html I have

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">
```

How to rename **csrfmiddlewaretoken**? I don't want, that users can know, that site uses Django.

I have nothing found in Django [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/), Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, the string is [hard-coded](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1101467ce0756272a54f4c7bc65c4c335a94111b/django/template/defaulttags.py#L59) in the Django source code. If you patch it, [patch both places](https://github.com/django/django/blob/731f313d604a6cc141f36d8a1ba9a75790c70154/django/middleware/csrf.py#L171).

Comment: What's wrong with users knowing you're using Django? As long as you're doing everything right...

Answer (score 1):

This is string is hardcoded in **django/middleware/csrf.py**:

```
        # Check non-cookie token for match.
        request_csrf_token = ""
        if request.method == "POST":
            request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')

        if request_csrf_token == "":
            # Fall back to X-CSRFToken, to make things easier for AJAX,
            # and possible for PUT/DELETE.
            request_csrf_token = request.META.get('HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN', '')
```

But there is exist one-way for you. You can add your on js-function which will add **HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN** to your POST requests.

Find more details [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/).